# Octave dlmread won't read date format

Tags: file-io, octave

I have a csv file, the one from https://www.kaggle.com/jolasa/waves-measuring-buoys-data-mooloolaba/downloads/waves-measuring-buoys-data-mooloolaba.zip/1. The first entries look like this:

[image: First entries of aforementioned file]

The first column has dates which I'm trying to read with this command:

```
matrix = dlmread ('waves-measuring-buoys-data/WavesMooloolabaJan2017toJun2019.csv',',',1,0);
```

(If referring to file on Kaggle, note that I slightly modified the directory and file names for ease of reading)

Then when I check a date by printing matrix(2,1), I get 1 instead of 01/01/2017 00:00.

How do I get the correct format?

Comment: Hi @Hiroshima! Welcome to Stack Overflow. The link to the CSV file you posted requires a login. Maybe you can just include it as an attachment here, or post it somewhere public that doesn't require a login?

Answer (score 0):

`csvread` is only for numeric inputs.

Use `csv2cell` from the `io` package instead, to obtain your data as a string, and then perform any necessary string operatios and conversions accordingly.