# Reading Date from CSV file in Octave

Tags: csv, octave

I want to read a CSV file in Octave which has a date column and 4 columns which are integers. I have used.

```
[num,txt,raw] = dlmread('Mitteilungen_data.csv');
ID = num(:,1) ;
DATE = datestr (date, yyyy-mm-dd) ;
FK_OBSERVERS= num(:,2) ;
GROUPS = num(:,3) ;
SUNSPOTS = num(:,4) ;
WOLF = num(:,5) ;
dn=datenum(DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD');
plot(dn,WOLF)
```

Sample Data:

```html
ID  DATE     FK_OBSERVERS GROUPS SUNSPOTS   WOLF

4939    1612-01-17  11  5   11  61
83855   1612-01-18  85  2   2   22
4940    1612-01-20  11  4   5   45
4941    1612-01-21  11  4   7   47
4942    1612-01-23  11  3   5   35
4943    1612-01-24  11  3   6   36
4944    1612-01-25  11  6   13  73
4945    1612-01-27  11  3   6   36
83856   1612-01-28  85  NULL    NULL    NULL
4946    1612-01-29  11  3   6   36
4947    1612-01-30  11  4   8   48
4948    1612-02-02  11  5   8   58
4949    1612-02-05  11  4   7   47
4950    1612-02-06  11  3   7   37
4951    1612-02-10  11  5   7   57
4952    1612-02-12  11  3   4   34
4953    1612-02-13  11  2   2   22
4954    1612-02-14  11  3   3   33
```

The Date column is showing an error: `element number 2 undefined in return list`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions of [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. Those languages are explicitly **not** the same, so only use both tags when explicitly asking about differences or similarities between the two. Don't tag spam.

Comment: @Shreya do you care if the solution is matlab-compatible or not particularly?

Comment: also please include a minimal example of the csv file that could be used to debug your script

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou    I am not  concerned about matlab compatibility. Here is a short excerpt of the table.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fmyTJVuACa5Uy-sTZiH9aBJ_sbNnNCY35s1Jl-0rWH4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Shreya the document is protected, but linking to a google doc is probably overkill anyway. Just edit your question and copy a couple of the offending lines there.

Comment: but, in any case, your problem is probably related to the fact that dlmread is only for numerical data. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58716737/4183191 / stackoverflow.com/a/62885690/4183191 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/61427318/4183191 ...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou  I have tried 'textscan' and it is working but it is not taking into account the dates. Somehow the "io" package is not getting reflected in the workspace after installing it. Hence, I am not able to use csv2cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
[num, txt, raw] = dlmread( %...
```

but dlmread does not return three outputs. Type `help dlmread` in your console to see the syntax.

What *does* seem to return these three arguments is the `xlsread` command. Perhaps you copied code that used xlsread?

However, even so, I would still use `csv2cell`. Type `csv2cell('data.csv')`  (where data.csv is the name of your file) to see what kind of output it gives

Before you can use any of the commands defined in the `io` package, you need to load it on your workspace.

```
pkg load io
```

Comment: @Shreya btw, having a look at your file, it might cause you problems because it's space delimited ... you _could_ try post-processing with strsplit to remove spaces ... but the easiest thing for you to do will be to preprocess your csv file by hand to convert to actual "comma-separated" format (and also remove empty lines)

Comment: The "dataframe" from "dataframe" package is also working fine for this format.